# How to use cmdline to send key `<ESC>`?

Tags: neovim

As title. I need to use this in a script to close the current floating window.

Comment: Probably with `feedkeys()`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Just realized that `nvim_feedkeys` is blocking and thus preferred in my use case (by hitting my foot with `nvim_input`). (late) Thanks for you kindly comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I spent a lot of time trying to go back to terminal-normal mode, and this works:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_feedkeys('', 't', true)
```

The invisible part in neovim looks like `^\^N`. And to make it work as expected you need to make sure that you don't do any "smart" remapping on neither `<C-N>` nor `<C-\\>` in Tmux or Alacritty configs. (I did :()

So to my original question `<Esc>` looks like `^[`, but in one (not two!) char.

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved this using NeoVIm by the way:

```
vim.keymap.set({'n', 't'}, '<M-Tab>', function ()
  if (vim.api.nvim_win_get_config(0).relative ~= '') then
    vim.api.nvim_input('<ESC>')
  end
  require('FTerm').toggle()
end, NOREF_NOERR_TRUNC)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also `:stopinsert`, which "works like typing `<Esc>` in Insert mode."

```
                            *:stopi* *:stopinsert*
:stopi[nsert]       Stop Insert mode or |Terminal-mode| as soon as
            possible.  Works like typing <Esc> in Insert mode.
            Can be used in an autocommand, example:  
                :au BufEnter scratch stopinsert
```